# Book where humans are considered extremely dangerous, but an alien ship comes looking for help

Tags: story-identification

One of my friends told me about this book/book series. Aliens aren't allowed to enter our solar system because we are too dangerous, but one ship comes to earth asking for help against one of their enemies. Humans have been used in wars in the galaxy or universe before and we were too destructive. We  were labeled as weapons of mass destruction and not to be contacted or interacted with. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Check out the literature section of this website:
http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HumansAreWarriors

Comment: @Dhrmllo: Well, there went a good twenty minutes.

Comment: @gnovice: You got out after only 20 minutes?  Lucky.

Comment: Pretty close to the short story "Danger - Human" by Gordon R Dickson.  The difference is they weren't looking for help, but just wanted to know why humans were considered so dangerous... and found out.  And also short story not a book or series.

Answer (score 14):

There are quite a few stories where humans are much better warriors compared to other species and used as mercenaries.  A little bit more details would help in narrowing down the list.

Two examples here.

- [Legacy of Aledanta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_of_the_Aldenata) series by John Ringo

  > One group of aliens comes to earth in search of warriors to fight
  >   against another set.
- The short story ["With Friends Like These"](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35128.With_Friends_Like_These_) by Alan Dean Foster.

  > Several alien races come in search of humanity and Earth after the
  >   planet and its inhabitants had been locked away for for millenia for
  >   being unable to play nice with the rest of the universe. Now they were
  >   desperately needed to defeat aggressive aliens known as Yops.

Comment: Yes, sounds like With Friends Like These, especially the bit about Earth being out of bounds.

Comment: Whenever you have an Idea for an interesting story someone comes along and steals it before you've even thought of it... Damn future theives

Comment: @SamIam George R. R. Martin actually wrote a short story about that idea - I'm pretty sure it was Unsound Variations, collected in [Portraits of his Children](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portraits_of_His_Children)

Comment: @user14111 My point was that even Sam I Am's "future thieves stealing my ideas before I think of them" concept has been written already :)

Comment: I remembered that the other races were physically inferior and fought their wars force on force in the way of the British Military during the American Revolution. Also that we were considered too extreme in our bloodlust and methods when it came to winning the battles that the other races tried to involve us in, which led to the quarantine of Earth from the rest of the universe.

Comment: @KyleStevenHagenbuch - Did this turn out to be the correct answer?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds similar to the book *The Excalibur Alternative* by David Weber.  It is available in several of the [Baen Free CDs](http://baencd.thefifthimperium.com/), notably the 'Mission of Honor' CD.

A single alien ship arrives at Earth, and seizes several ships worth of medieval English soldiers (knights, infantry, and archers) from a storm which would have certainly destroyed the entire fleet.  These soldiers are used by the aliens to serve as a 'brute squad' of sorts.  They fight battles for the aliens so that the aliens can secure mining rights (or rights to other planetary resources) on planets which, by law, the aliens themselves cannot attack.

The aliens were inspired by a different group of aliens (a different species, or possibly just a different corporation) which had previously had great success doing the same thing with a Roman legion.  Their success was so great, in fact, that a law had been passed forbidding the use of humans in this manner.

The aliens who abducted the English are in violation of this law, and are simply trying to turn as much profit as possible before they are discovered.

The humans eventually discover this, as well as a secret which gives them a chance to turn the tables on the aliens.

Answer (score 1):

This is the book, [The Human Chronicles](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005VGB16A).

> Humans may not be the strongest, or the fastest or the most
>   coordinated, but no race in the galaxy combines all these traits into
>   one being to such a degree as we do.

Comment: Can you explain why do you think this is the book?

Comment: There isn't a book by that name. That name describes a book *series*

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like [*The Damned* trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Damned_Trilogy) by Alan Dean Foster.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Could you explain why you believe this matches the OP's description, please? Answers without explanation are likely to end up getting downvoted and/or deleted.