# Giant alien snail monitors region of space waiting for evil Ancients to awake

Tags: story-identification

The story is about a giant alien snail who monitors a region of space waiting for the Ancients to awake - and they're not good. When the Ancients awake the "snails" seek help from humans. Earth decides to help and bring their moon with them.

Answer (score 2):

Been a few years, but is sounds like "With Friends Like These" by Alan Dean Foster.  Aliens come to Earth looking for help against some enemy and discover the humans living as simple farmers. However, they live that way by choice and are actually so advanced they prefer to live a simple agrarian lifestyle. In the end the aliens draft them into their cause and the humans move Earth and the Moon to follow the aliens.

[With Friends Like These by Alan Dean Foster](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345323904)

[Found the full text of the short story. OP can check it out and validate if this is what they remember.](https://www.reddit.com/r/HFY/comments/2b79sa/text_with_friends_like_these_alan_dean_foster/)

Comment: That matches the "bring their moon along", but not the giant snail or any of the rest. To be honest it sounds like OP is conflating two separate stories.

Comment: see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83339/story-about-planet-urth for an answer with some excerpts to this story